# Login in first HTML automatically redirect and login to second HTML passing values from first html

Tags: javascript, html

Can you please give me an idea how to do this in a way that when I login in Login1.html when user selects TEAM in the dropdown it will automatically redirect and login to Login2.html using the values I entered in Login1.html and when user selects Premium it will automatically redirected on Premium page. 
HTML and javascript only.

This is my  first html Login1.html

```
    <form name="ctlogin" id="ctlogin">
       <label  class="label-style" id="login_label">Login</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="selection" id="dropdown" >
        <option value="premium" id="ct_premium">Premium</option>
        <option value="team" id="ct_team">Team</option>
       </select>
        <input class="form-control"  type="tel" id="mobile-number"  >
        <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password"  >
        <input type="submit" class="button1" value=" " id="loginButton" >     
       </form>
```

This is my second html Login2.html

```
      <form  name="teamlogin" style="" method="post" action="en.html" >
       <label>Login</label>
       <input class="form-control "  type="tel" id="mobilenumber" name="mobilenumber" >
       <input class="form-control " id="password" type="password">
         <input type="image" id="registerButton"  src="img/green check.png">     
      /form>
```

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For substitution of arguments clientside, you can parse `window.location.search` in javascript on Login2 page. Something like

```
window.location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(e) {
    var pair = e.split("=")
    var input = document.querySelector("[name='"+pair[0]+"']")
    if (input) input.value = pair[1]
})
```

Note that for this to work `input` fields all must have names, matching on both pages.

---

For redirection, you might use handler `<select onchange='selected()'>` and corresponding javascript code:

```
function selected(event) {
    var form = document.querySelector("form#ctlogin")
    var sel = document.querySelector("select#dropdown").value
    // Here you set it where to redirect the page:
    if (sel === "team") form.action = "Login2.html"
    ...
    form.submit()
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks to you... but do you know how can I set the value or text of textbox in Login2.html with the values I entered in Login1.html? Thanks in advance

Comment: My first code snipped should do that, insert it into Login2.html

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks.. It worked when I insert it after the textbox :) hahaha because at first I insert it on the head...God bless you!

Comment: Acually, it's always better to wrap it in a function, for example `function loaded() { ...here the snippet... }` and attach to loading event: `<body onload='loaded()'>`. It's the way you should run your scripts.